# JMeter gives “The target server failed to respond ” Error

Tags: apache, jmeter

We use Jmeter to do performance testing. I gave 200 threads(200 users). and we have  two servers. like sever A, Server B. i tested indivisibly for 200 Users, it works. and we load balancing server Like server C. So request goes to ether server A Or Server B. But if configure my same jmx script(200 thread) with Server C. it gives error below (but it works for 50 users-- no error).

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:95)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:61)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:289)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:252)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.receiveResponseHeader(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:201)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:300)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:127)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the issue can be reproduced only on higher loads - it's definitely a server (or load balancer) issue so congratulations on finding the first [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing).

Now you can investigate the reason and suggest the fixes, the next steps could be:

1. Inspect application under test / load balancer logs - you can find a clue there
2. Inspect application under test / load balancer / database / any other middleware configuration. in the majority of cases default configuration is good for development and debugging but you will need to perform some [performance tuning](https://stackify.com/web-performance-optimization/) before running a prod-like load test
3. Collect main health metrics on the application under test side (CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, Swap usage, etc.). It might be the case your application simply lacks hardware resources. You can use built-in tools of the operating system(s) or an [APM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management) tool or [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)
4. Re-run your test with a [profiling tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) telemetry enabled on the application under test side. This will give you an overview with regards to where the application spends the most time, which are the "heaviest" functions or functions called most frequently so you would know what to optimise.
5. Make sure that the load balancer equally (or according to the other [algorithm](https://kemptechnologies.com/load-balancer/load-balancing-algorithms-techniques/)) distributes the requests between the backend servers. It might be the case you're hitting only one server, if this is - consider adding the [DNS Cache Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dns-cache-manager-right-way-test-load-balanced-apps) to your Test Plan and re-run your test to see if it helps.